# Сервер на локальной машине работает в несколько раз медленнее, чем на хостинге

Tags: веб-сервер, windows, apache

Есть дикий скрипт, обновляющий страницу 5 раз в секунду. На хостинге работает как надо, на локальном компьютере раз в 5 медленнее.

Веб-сервером служит `OpenServer`. Ставил Ubuntu, веб-сервер на стандартных настройках - получилось совсем немного быстрее.

Вопрос: всё дело в настройках или есть какая-то хитрая магия? Может кто-то подсказать, что за настройки или, что за магия?

```
OS Windows 8Процессор: i5 3550 3.2x4Память: 8GB DDR3Мат.плата: Z77-D3H
```

Comment: UPD: SSD и отключенный xdebug решили проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> На хостинге работает как надо, на локальном компьютере раз в 5 медленнее

Очевидно, такая прибавка к скорости зависит от железа хостера. Вы не знаете его состав?

Comment: К сожалению, не нашёл, но это виртуальный хостинг и мне там много не дадут. Неужели обычного ПК недостаточно, чтобы отработал скрипт на подключение, загрузку записи из 4х полей и её сохранения?

Comment: Стоп. О каком подключении идет речь? Если скрипт медленно работает именно в сетевом плане, то возможно, у хостера более выгодное положение относительно хоста, к которому подключается Ваш скрипт. Либо у него просто более мощная сетевая инфраструктура (оптика, гигабиты в сетевом железе и т.п.)   --  Т.е., в таком случае, от **вычислительных** мощностей зависимостей меньше, чем от **сетевых**.

Comment: Нет, на локальном компьютере абсолютно всё работает локально, потому и вопрос. Подключение к БД.

Comment: БД - это диски. У хостера может стоять какая-нить параллельная SAN(Storage Area Network). Т.е., опять же - превалируют **накопительные** мощности.   --  Вариантов может быть много, пока не станет известна разница в железе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, попробую узнать, что же там за железо такое.